# How is it possible to compress matter infinitely like in a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, singularities, matter

How can a star that turns into a black hole technically be smaller than a quark? 
$10^{12}$ atoms $\geq$ 1 quark. That shouldn't work.

Comment: You left out a lot of zeros!

Comment: According to the Schwarzschild metric, the volume inside the black hole is infinite, so the average density is zero.

Comment: @safesphere : I am not sure how good it is to talk about a "volume inside" the black hole. To talk about volume, i.e. 3-dimensional, we need to be able to have a sensible way to pick a 3-dimensional space-like slice of an object with which to find that - essentially, what the object looks like "now". But in a curved spacetime - esp. the extreme one of a black hole - there is essentially no non-arbitrary notion of "now" at all: no well-defined global simultaneity. In what way is one defining the "volume", then?

Comment: @The_Sympathizer We can define it as a Schwarzschild time slice. Then the symmetry is preserved and the volume geometry is a hypersurface of a spherindle. To visualize it in the reduced number of dimensions, it is like a surface of a thin cylinder shrinking in radius over time from the Schwarzschild radius to zero. The singularity is the axis of the cylinder not located anywhere in space (surface). So while inside, an observer cannot see or point to a singularity. It does not exist yet (is in the future) at any moment of time inside the BH. See the 3D diagram linked in my comment below.

Answer (score 3):

For one thing, actually, we *don't* know if it is possible to "compress matter infinitely". The idea that matter becomes infinitely compressed comes from our best theory - general relativity - of how space and time work: once you compress matter to within a suitably small *finite* volume, it must continue to compress itself no matter how strong it otherwise would be or how much matter you have, and hence has no alternative but to compress to a size of zero. In effect, space and time distort in such a way that there are no permissible movements anymore except those which serve to push things closer together.

But the trouble is, our *other* best theory of physics - quantum mechanics - which is the theory of how *matter* works, doesn't like that (for reasons too complicated to get into here)! It doesn't like the idea of infinitely compressed matter. Hence, either one or both of these has to be wrong, so it may be that matter *doesn't* "compress infinitely". Or maybe it does - the problem is, we can't know, and those that state this as a "truth" are being sloppy and misleading.

But if you want to nonetheless insist on the idea, then a rather simple intuitive idea for how a zillion atoms *could* compress themselves into a point, would have to be this. The particles that make up atoms (quarks and electrons) are, themselves, point-sized (quantum has no problem with that; it's with trying to smash a bunch of them together that it starts running into issues - as said, this is an oversimplified, intuitive idea). Thus they already have size zero. Matter, essentially, is entirely empty space, while it's forces that those zero-size particles project onto each other that give it the appearance of shape and extent. Compressing those particles *all* to a point, then, just means taking away all that empty space between them. A black hole core is matter with no empty space left in it at all. Since a zillion zeros add to zero, a zillion point-size particles add to a single point, and the result is that they all occupy one and the same point.

Comment: "*how a zillion atoms could compress themselves into a point*" - The Schwarzschild singularity is not a point. The worldline of the BH center is an infinitely long line $(r=0; -\infty<t<+\infty)$ where $r$ is timelike while $t$ is spacelike. So the singularity is an infinitely long spacelike line that exists for a zero period of time.

Comment: @safesphere : Hmm. However, I'd raise that the analogy is still useful because, for one, you still have the problem of a 3-dimensional object then becoming 1-dimensional and, for another, actually, elementary particles are themselves "lines" too, when you consider their temporal extent given that we are necessarily talking about space-time here and so have to be consistent in the picture we're using. In a sense, the black hole singularity "lives sideways" - its history stretched "horizontally" across space as though it were travelling faster than light - as compared to other objects.

Comment: I think the key here is that each particle ends up in a different point of the singularity. As an illustration, imagine a handful of sand. Then, instead of trying to squeeze it into a smaller volume, spread it into a one-grain thin line. This way no two particles are squeezed into each other and don't need to have a very high Fermi temperature. Once matter is spread this way, squeezing each particle into a zero volume is not a problem, because particles are poinike anyway, as you stated in the answer.

Comment: "*elementary particles are themselves 'lines' too*" - Yes, but worldliness of particles are perpendicular to the line of the singularity. See the geodesic chart here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2929400/ - It also shows that different particles end up in different "points" of the singularity ("points" in the asymptotic sense).

Answer (score -1):

The existence of a singularity at the center of a black hole is often taken as proof that the Theory of General Relativity has broken down, which is perhaps not unexpected as it occurs in conditions where quantum effects should become important. However, as is shown below it tells us the strength of the gravitational field at the event horizon of one cause time to stop for all observers. The question is, “How can matter move beyond it if time has stopped with respect to it?” Since motion is define as the change in an objects position over time General Theory of Relatively does not break down because it tells us the movement of all matter must also stop at that point. Therefore, according to its laws it cannot continue to collapse to the point called a singularity.

Even so, in 1939 Robert Oppenheimer and Snyder using Einstein’s theories described how infalling matter would be in free fall after passing through one.  This is the bases for the conclusion that a singularity is found at the center of black hole.  However, as will be shown that is not consistent with his theories.

Einstein told us that time is dilated by a gravitational field. Therefore, the time dilation will increase relative to an external observer as it approaches its event horizon because the gravitational field at its surface increases until it becomes frozen at its critical circumference.

This means, matter moves slower as it approach one from the perspective of an external observer and stops when reaching it. This is because the gravitational slowing of time according to his theory stops or becomes infinitely dilated when it reaches it. Therefore, from that perspective it could not continue to free fall beyond its event horizon as Robert Oppenheimer and Snyder suggested because movement cannot occur if time has stopped.

However, it also tells us, according to the laws of physics developed by Einstein a singularity cannot form because nothing can pass through it even horizon from the perspective of an external observer. Therefore, the laws he defined are not violated with respect to external observers.

Yet, Einstein developed his Theory of Relativity based on the equivalence of all inertial reference frames which he defined as ones that move freely under their own inertia because they are not pushed not pulled by a force.
This means that one can view the time dilation caused differential gravitational potential between its center and event horizon.

(Einstein would have considered this point an inertial one with respect to its gravitational field because the field on one side will be offset by the one on the other side. Therefore, he would have considered it to be one because an observer at its center would not be “pushed or pulled and would move onward with the same motion as the gravitational field of the black hole.)

However, some have suggested if the collapse was uneven, it could not be considered one because its center would be “pushed or pulled” due to the differential gravitational force cause by its collapse. But the laws governing time dilation in Einstein's theory tell us time would move slower for those objects as they get closer to the event horizon allowing the ones further away to catch up. This tells us matter at every point where it is infalling will be at the event horizon at the exact same time and its center will not experience any pushing or pulling. Therefore, it could be considered an inertial reference frame.)

Therefore, the movement of matter towards the surface of black hole from perspective of its center would look according to Einstein’s field equations as slowing to a crawl as it nears it because of the gravitational time dilation until it becomes frozen at the event horizon.

Therefore, because time stops or becomes frozen at the critical circumference for all observers who are at its center matter cannot continue to move towards it from their perspectives.

Many physicists assume the mass of a star implodes when it reaches the critical circumference. Therefore, an observer on the surface of that star will be in free fall with respect to its gravitational field when as it passes through its critical circumference.

This indicates a point on its surface, according to Einstein's theories could also be considered an inertial reference frame because an observer who is in free fall riding on it will not experience its gravitational forces
However, according to the Einstein theory, as a star nears its critical circumference an observer who is freefalling on its surface will perceive the differential magnitude of the gravitational field relative to an observer who is in an external reference frame or is at its center to be increasing.
Therefore, he or she will perceive time in those reference frames that are not freefalling towards it slowing to a crawl as it approaches the critical circumference. The closer it gets the slower time moves with respect to all external reference frame including the one that exist at its center and stops with respect to them before when it reaches it.

However, the contraction of a star's surface must be measured with respect to the external reference frames in which it is contracting. But as mentioned earlier Einstein's theories indicate time in the external environment of an object or the center of a black hole it was freefalling into it would become infinitely dilated or stop when it reaches its critical circumference.  Therefore, because motion cannot occur if time has stopped it could not move beyond the critical circumference of a black hole.

As mentioned earlier many physicists assume that the matter will be in free fall after passing through the event horizon of a black hole.
However, the movement of matter towards one must be measured with respect to all reference frames.

Yet, as was just shown Einstein’s theories indicate time on event horizon stops when viewed from all reference frames.

Therefore, because the Laws of Relativistic physics tell us that time stops or becomes frozen at the event horizon with respect to all observer’s matter cannot move beyond it.

However, it also tells us, the laws of relativistic physics are not violated in black hole because of the time dilation associated with its gravitational field, the collapse of matter cannot proceed beyond its event horizon to form a singularity.